# Jquery Next/NextAll/NextUntil with count limit

Tags: jquery, siblings

Its really annoying me that I don't know the answer to this, I thought it would be simple. I want to get the next and previous elements from a selected element to a limit (say 2). Here is an example:

```
<ul>
<li>link 1</li>
<li>link 2</li>
<li>link 3</li>
<li>link 4</li>
<li class='active'>link 1</li>
<li>link 6</li>
<li>link 7</li>
<li>link 8</li>
<li>link 9</li>
</ul>
```

So I want to select two elements before and 2 elements after the active `li`. I have tried doing something like:
`$('li.active').nextAll(':eq(2)');` and then adding it to the same using `prevAll` but it selects one element 2 siblings away instead of the whole group.

There must be an easy way of doing this that I have missed, any suggestions?

N.B. I cant edit the HTML, it is generated dynamically.

Comment: Iv managed to do it with the following:
.nextAll(':eq(0), :eq(1)');
this seems untidy, surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are (at least) two approaches to this problem. You can chain [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) into [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), then use [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to combine the two sets:

```
var $active = $("li.active");
var $around = $active.prevAll().slice(0, 2)
                     .add($active.nextAll().slice(0, 2));
```

Or you can fetch the [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the active element, use `slice()` to get siblings around that index, then filter the active element out with [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
var $active = $("li.active");
var activeIndex = $active.index();
var $around = $active.siblings().addBack()
                     .slice(Math.max(0, activeIndex - 2), activeIndex + 3)
                     .not($active);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing alternatives, I dont think either of these are as quick or concise as using .nextAll(':eq(0), :eq(1)'); it surprises me there is not an easier way to do this however.

Comment: I put all these ideas through jsPerf and interestingly using .prevAll().slice(0, 2) was the quickest:
http://jsperf.com/selecting-limited-elements

Answer (score 4):

You  can use `nextAll` and `prevAll` combined with the [*less-than* `:lt(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector
(*in your case `:lt(2)`*)

```
var current = $('.active'),
    next = current.nextAll(':lt(2)'),
    prev = current.prevAll(':lt(2)'),
    all = current.add(next).add(prev);
```

Comment: Good thought, thanks for the suggestion. Take a look:
http://jsperf.com/selecting-limited-elements

Comment: Yes, performance is discussed in the ***Additional Notes*** section of the documentation of the `:lt` selector.. (*but for casual in-page use*) it is not really an issue.