# How to calculate the table row that has rowspan attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I am creating a table structure dynamically. When I click a package I am inserting child row to the table and added a rowspan value with the count of the child value. Now I have to number the row I used index of the row but when there is row span It should consider the whole row as say 1 next number must be 2. And When I click remove I need to remove all child row that are row spanned. 
Here is a code I have implemented,

```
  var rowspans;
  var servicecount;
  var cnt;
  var ser = [];
  var refForEmployee = new Firebase("https://kekranmekrandubai.firebaseio.com/package");

  refForEmployee.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var list = [];

    for (var key in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        name = data[key].image ? data[key].image : '';
        emp_name = data[key].package_name ? data[key].package_name : '';
        service = data[key].service ? data[key].service : '';
        servicecount = service.length;

        console.log("service data");
        console.log(service);
        console.log(servicecount);
        if (name.trim().length > 0) {
          list.push({
            image: name,
            emp_name: emp_name,
            services: service
          })
        }
      }
    }
    // refresh the UI
    refreshUI(list);


  });
  function refreshUI(list) {
    var lis = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var empname = list[i].emp_name;
      var serc = [];
      serc = list[i].services;
      lis += '<div class="outlining"><div class="customize"><img class="employeeimages" src="' + list[i].image + '"></img><img src="img/bookingemployeeid.png" class="employee_id_display"><p class="firstname">' + list[i].emp_name + '<p class="lastname">Last name</p><p class="emps_id">1001</p><p class="arrays">' + serc + '</p></div></div>';

    };

    document.querySelector('#employee_list').innerHTML = lis;
  };
  $('body').on('click', '.employeeimages', function() {
    var name = $(this).closest('.customize').find('.firstname').text();
    var service = [];
    service = $(this).closest('.customize').find('.arrays').text();
    console.log(service);

    //var myString = "Mr. Jack Adams";
    // Create a variable to contain the array
    var mySplitResult;
    // Use the string.split function to split the string
    mySplitResult = service.split(",");
    for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {

      console.log(mySplitResult[i]);
      $("#booktable").append('<tr><td><div class="maindiv"><div class="productdiv"><p class="select_product">Select Items</p></div><div class="employeediv"><p>' + mySplitResult[i] + '</p></div><div class="pricediv">Price</div></div></td></tr>');

    }
    rowspans = mySplitResult.length;
    get_values(name, table_selected_index);

    $(".select_employee_div").css("display", "none");

  });
  //booking main table
  //add row to booking table
  $(".useradd").click(function() {
    var rows = $('#booktable tr').length;
    var rowcount = rows + 1;

    $("#booktable").append('<tr><td id=' + rowcount + ' class="f">' + rowcount + '</td><td><div class="maindiv"><div class="productdiv"><p class="select_product">Select Items</p></div><div class="employeediv"><input type="button" class="select_employee" value="Select Employee"></div><div class="pricediv">Price</div><div class="actiondiv"><input type="button" value="x" class="remove"/></div></div></td></tr>');
  });

  //remove row and dynamically changing the index value of the removed row

  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var table = 'booktable';
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    setTimeout(function() { // Simulating ajax
      var siblings = row.siblings();
      row.remove();
      siblings.each(function(index) {
        $(this).children().first().text(index + 1);
      });
    }, 100);
  });

  $('#booktable').on('click', '.select_employee', function() {
    $(".select_employee_div").css("display", "block");
    var indexOfTheChangedRow = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    table_selected_index = indexOfTheChangedRow;

  });

  function get_values(val, rowIndex) {
    console.log("inside get_values function");

    console.log(val);

    $('#booktable tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ')').find(".select_employee").val(val);
    $('#booktable tr:eq(' + rowIndex + ')').find(".f").attr("rowspan", rowspans + 1)

  };
```

This is my table structure I need

￼
￼[image]

Here is a fiddle demo that I have implement. I am struck with changing the row index and remove action.[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anusibi/s2bod97t/65/) Please help me code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain _I need to remove all child row that are row spanned_ ?

Comment: Thank you. I will explain @ Rayon Dabre ...I have a row with row span value say 3, then from that current row and next 3 rows must be deleted. because they are the child roes that are row spanned.

Comment: A loop after remove action ?

Comment: Yes.But It should happen when a single remove is clicked @RayonDabre

Comment: @Anu -   Just a personnel suggestion, its not appropriate to share the actual Service URL for numerous reason, your company may have signed NDA which could land you or anyone in trouble!

Comment: @Anu, After remove, loop through all the elements and update your properties...

Comment: I am struck with that. Rows are removed incorrectly. I couldnt detect the problem with that code. Can you please refer my fiddle and help me @RayonDabre

Comment: Thank you @RohitTiwari. I will not do that again.But need to show a demo of what I am really struck :(

Comment: Have you tried using **$('tr>td[rowspan]').length** ?

Comment: Thank you @Vixed that works really fine for indexing my table row. How do I remove the rows all together when the parent row is remove? Can you please help me?

Comment: If you have to remove all rows use **$('tr').remove()** or if you want to remove all row with rowspan **$('td[rowspan]').closest('tr').remove()**

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vixed..I need to remove specific rows. like if I have a a row that is having row span 3 then if I click that row next 2 rows that are combined to it should also be remove

Comment: I dont want to remove all rows with row span. Can you please see my fiddle for demo else see the image I have posted when I click delete in bridal package it should remove the next two rows also @Vixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below for removing the row base on rowspan and reIndex the remaining row:

```
$('body').on('click','.remove',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var row=$(this).closest('tr');
    var rowspan=parseInt(row.children().first().attr('rowspan'));

    //remove row
    if (isNaN(rowspan)) {
        row.remove();
    } else {
        $('#booktable tr').slice(row.index(), row.index() + rowspan).remove();
    }


    //reindex
    var newIndex = 0;
    $('#booktable tr').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).children().first().attr('id') !== undefined) {
            newIndex++;
            $(this).children().first().text(newIndex);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot @dee.ronin... Removing row was perfectly working but re indexing is somewhat problematic please refer this link https://fiddle.jshell.net/anusibi/s2bod97t/116/

Comment: i see that the behavior of indexing was change. Updated code to add variable newIndex. You can try the updated code.

Answer (score 8):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var row=$(this).closest('tr');
    row.nextAll().each(function(){
        if ($('td',this).is('[rowspan]')){
            $(this).remove()
        } else {
         row.remove(); // before exit from loop
         return false;
        }
    })
    row.remove(); //for the last TR
    $('tr').each(function(i) {
        $('td:first',this).text(i+1); //For re-index
    });
})
```

Or if you need to remove only the first and the next 2 rows, this should fix your problem:

```
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    row.add(row.nextAll().slice(0,2)).remove();
});
```

Thanks to the answare: [Jquery Next/NextAll/NextUntil with count limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244327/jquery-next-nextall-nextuntil-with-count-limit)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vixed.. The first solution removes only the first row. And In second solution Can we send index  dynamically to slice method so that it works fine with my code?

Comment: I used this following code. $("body").on("click", ".remove", function(event) {
    var table = 'booktable';
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var rowspans1 = rowspans+1;
    row.add(row.nextAll().slice(0,rowspans)).remove();

   setTimeout(function() {
      var siblings = row.siblings();
           siblings.each(function(index) {
        $(this).children().first().text(index + 1);
      });
    }, 100);
  });

Comment: But I am not able to re index and remove index correctly @Vixed... Please help me

Comment: It works at end of the table but not inbetween@Vixed

Comment: I'll work on it later.. sorry @Anu, right now I can't.

Comment: I've added the a function for re-index. Let me know, and please, can you check the answer?

Comment: No Its not working I have updated the fiddle :( @Vixed

Comment: This code is removing all child element that is rowspaned @Vixed :(

Comment: @Anu please refer to the last edited answer, I added an index function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98002/discussion-between-anu-and-vixed).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vixed. I used that code. if i have 3 rows with rowspan now on clicking all rows with no rowspan attribute. and reindex is done
sorry on clicking remove
can slice be used dynamically? else can nextuntil used?

Comment: above answer that I have accepted works fine. refer with that.. @Vixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value of rowspan to count how many rows you have to delete **$('td:first',row).attr('rowspan')-1**

**http://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/af0Ljbzt/**

```
  $('body').on('click', '.remove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var row=$(this).closest('tr');
    row.nextAll().slice(0,$('td:first',row).attr('rowspan')-1).each(function(){
      $(this).remove()
    });
    row.remove();
    $('tr:has(".f")').each(function(i) {
        $('td.f',this).text(i+1);
    });
  });
```

Comment: At the end... we see the sun.

Comment: If I select the employee which already has data overwrites  and mess up the structure :( @Vixed