# jQuery eq() with different class name

Tags: jquery

I have following html:

```
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block first"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block">this</div> // I need to target this to add another class
<div class="block"></div>
```

I want to select 3rd from the "block first" div:

```
$(".block.first").eq(3).addClass("last");
```

Of course I am missing something. The "first" class is dynamically added to one of the "block" div and I need to target 3rd div from where the "first" class is added. Anyone with suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Third where? Child, sibling, parent .... ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant third div from the "block first". I added a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Next/NextAll/NextUntil with count limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244327/jquery-next-nextall-nextuntil-with-count-limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [$.fn.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$('.block.first').nextAll('.block').eq(2).addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can get the index of the `.block.first` element, then select the element three after that. Try this:

```js
var blockFirstIndex = $('.block.first').index();
$('.block').eq(blockFirstIndex + 2).addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: #c00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">block</div>
<div class="block first">block first</div>
<div class="block">block</div>
<div class="block">block</div>
<div class="block">this // I need to target this to add another class</div>
<div class="block">block</div>
```